# Query to retrieve the data for the particular month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in which there is 12 column for each month.the Column name like Jan, Feb,Mar,Apr etc . Now i wants to write a query in which I will pass the date or month and in return it should show only get that Month column.

Comment: I have just one question, WHY?

Comment: beacuse I am create a report in which I need to have only those record that has been changed for respective  month.

Comment: I meant, why is there even a table with a column for each month? There should be a table with a datetime and use ``select ... from table groupby month(datecolumn)`` to get results for each month, I dont see why a table with 12 individual columns makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth VARCHAR(12) = 'Januari';

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT [' + @CurrentMonth + '] FROM [dbo].[Mytable];';

exec sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement
```

You need to use dynamic T-SQL statement. Note, if you want to wrapped this in a routine it should be stored procedure because you cannot execute `dynamic T-SQL` in function (for example, except SQL CLR is used).

Comment: That doesnt parse a datetime to the month name.

Comment: @RandRandom He said month or date. I gave him example with month.

Comment: @RandRandom We will see.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth VARCHAR(30) = '2017-11-10 11:57:18.970';

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @DynamicTSQLStatement=N'SELECT [' +
    CASE WHEN isdate(@CurrentMonth)=1  then DATENAME(MONTH,@CurrentMonth) 
                ELSE @CurrentMonth END + '] FROM [dbo].[Mytable];';

exec sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement
```